# Sql query to get list of unique styles

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table data in this form:

> Catalog   Styles A          font-size:10px;display:none; A
>   display:none; B
>   font-size:12px;text-align:center;vertical-align:center; A
>   font-size:12px;text-align:center;

I want to get list of all the unique css style for each catalog in given data.
For A i have

> font-size;text-align;display;

what will be my query for this content?

Comment: You want a merge of all styles of a single catalog? I don't think that's doable...

Comment: First, try [SQL_split_values_to_multiple_rows] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows). Second, use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get your unique css style for each catalog. Third, use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get your result.